# Embedding Matplotlib in PyQt

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, backend

I am trying to test if Matplotlib works in PyQt on Ubuntu. I have been working with PyQt and I want to embed Matplotlib in Pyqt. I followed the code given at http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/01/20/matplotlib-with-pyqt-guis/ but It generates some errors while importing the `matplotlib`.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4agg.py", line 9, in <module>
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/figure.py", line 18, in <module>
    from axes import Axes, SubplotBase, subplot_class_factory
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/axes.py", line 2, in <module>
    import math, sys, warnings, datetime, new
  File "/home/kasa/Desktop/new.py", line 25, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
ImportError: cannot import name FigureCanvasQTAgg
```

I run these import commands from terminal and it works fine. 
Can someone figure out whats wrong with my installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the traceback.

You tried to import `FigureCanvasQTAgg` from `backend_qt4agg`:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
```

It tried to import `Figure` from `figure`:

```
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4agg.py", line 9, in <module>
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
```

which tried to import several things from `axes`:

```
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/figure.py", line 18, in <module>
    from axes import Axes, SubplotBase, subplot_class_factory
```

It imports several modules as well. Notice the last one, `new`:

```
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/axes.py", line 2, in <module>
    import math, sys, warnings, datetime, new
```

and where does it look for it? Instead of the built-in module, it goes to

```
  File "/home/kasa/Desktop/new.py", line 25, in <module>
```

which, I suppose is your file and it goes back again:

```
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
```

Python realizes that it can't import `FigureCanvasQTAgg` because it finds itself in a circular import hell, thus the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name FigureCanvasQTAgg
```

**Long story short**

Your file masks the built-in [`new` module](http://docs.python.org/library/new.html). Solution is simple: Rename the file (and also remove the `new.pyc` from the folder).